# Compile multiple LaTeX files w/ GitLab CI

Tags: latex, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pdflatex, gitlab-ci-runner

### Problem

I write down lectures at university in LaTeX (which is really convenient for this purpose), and i want `tex` files to automatically compile in `pdf`.

I have couple of `.tex` files in my repository like this:

```
.
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
└── lectures
    ├── math
    |   ├── differentiation
    |   |   ├── lecture_math_diff.tex
    |   |   ├── chapter_1.tex
    |   |   └── chapter_2.tex
    |   └── integration
    |       ├── lecture_math_int.tex
    |       ├── chapter_1.tex
    |       └── chapter_2.tex
    └── physics
        └── mechanics
            ├── lecture_physics_mech.tex
            ├── chapter_1.tex
            └── chapter_2.tex
```

So main file, for example, `lecture_math_diff.tex` using

```
\include{chapter_1}
\include{chapter_2}
```

tags, to form whole lecture.

And as result, i want to have my build artifacts in pdf like this:

```
├── math
|   ├── lecture_math_diff.pdf
|   └── lecture_math_int.pdf
└── physics
    └── lecture_physics_mech.pdf
```

---

What can be done here? Do i have to write any `sh` script to collect all `tex` files or use gitlab runners?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use a short script (e.g python or bash) and to run `latexmk` to generate the PDF files.

`latexmk` is a perl script, which compiles latex files automatically. A short introduction can be found [here](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html)

With python3 the script could look like the following one:

```py
# filename: make_lectures.py
import os
from subprocess import call

# configuration:
keyword_for_main_tex = "lecture"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    tex_root_directory = os.getcwd()

    for root, _, files in os.walk("."):
       for file_name in files:
            # check, if file name ends with `tex` and starts with the keyword
            if file_name.endswith("tex") and file_name.startswith(keyword_for_main_tex):
                os.chdir(root) # go in the directory
                call(['latexmk', '-lualatex', file_name]) # run latexmk on the main file
                os.chdir(tex_root_directory) # go back to root directory in case of relative paths
```

This script assumes, that only files to be compiled to PDF start with the keyword `lecture` (as in the question). But the `if` statement, which checks for files to build, could also be extended to more elaborate comparison as matching regular expressions.
`latexmk` is called with the command line flag `-lualatex` here to demonstrate how to configure the build process gloally. A local configuration possibility (for each single project) is given with [`.latexmkrc`](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html#local-configuration-files) files, which are read and processed by `latexmk`.

If we call `latexmk` as shell command, we have to make sure, that it is installed on our gitlab runner (and also `texlive`). If `Docker`container runners are registered (see [here](https://gitlab.dep.state.fl.us/help/ci/docker/using_docker_images.md) how it is done), then you just need to specify the name of an image from [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/), which leads to the example `gitlab-ci.yml` file below:

```
compile_latex_to_pdf:
  image: philipptempel/docker-ubuntu-tug-texlive:latest
  script: python3 make_lectures.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./*.pdf
    expire_in: 1 week
```

Fell free, to change the image to any other image you like (e.g. `blang/latex:latest`). Note, that the artifacts extraction assumes, that no other PDF files are in the repository.

A final remark: I did not try it, but it should also be possible to install `texlive` and `latexmk` directly on the gitlab runner (if you have access to it).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at https://github.com/reallyinsane/mathan-latex-maven-plugin. With the maven or gradle plugin you can also use "dependencies" for your projects.